# How to get first element of a List in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have an object with a list of nested objects. I want to get just the first element of the list and show one of it's properties.

Example:

```
public class Person {
    List<Phone> phones;
}

public class Phone {
    String type;
    String number;
}
```

Here I only want to get the persons first phone (`phones.get(0)` in java), and show the `phone.numer` attribute.

I started as follows, which work, BUT shows ANY phone numbers:

```
<field name="phones" class="java.util.List"/>
<jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{phones})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:listContents>
        <textField>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:listContents>
</jr:list>
```

I also tried the following approach:

```
<field name="phones" class="java.util.List" />
<field name="phoneFirst" class="my.package.Phone">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$F{phones}.get(0)]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="phoneFirstNumber" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$F{phoneFirst}.getNumber()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Result:
`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : $F{phones}.get(0)`

So, how can I tell `JasperReports` to just take the first element of the collection?

Answer (score -4):

I would do this in Java:

```
public class Person {
    List<Phone> phones;
    ...
    public Phone getFirstPhone() { 
        if(this.phones != null) {
            return this.phones.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

and then something like this in the JRXML:

```
<field name="firstPhoneNumber" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$F{firstPhone}.getNumber()]</fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Comment: I want to use an autogenerated complex xml webservice response object, thus cannot modify the class. I hoped I could achieve this in jreports for not having to introduce a jasper transfer object...

Comment: I would love to know what is wrong with my answer to warrant 3 downvotes.

Comment: There is nothing in the original question which states that the Person class cannot be modified.